# Identity Theorem for functions in $\textbf{K}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ on dense sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in \textbf{K}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ and let $U \subseteq dom(\varphi_1) \cap dom(\varphi_2)$ be a dense subset in $\mathbb{A}^2$, such that $\varphi_1(x) = \varphi_2(x)$ for all $x \in U$. Then $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2$.

First the definitions:

> Let $\mathbb{A}^2$ be the affine plane over an algebraically closed field $K$ and let $\textbf{K}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ denote the field of fractions of $K[X,Y]$. When talking about open sets in $\mathbb{A}^2$ we mean open concerning the Zariski Topology. Finally $dom(\varphi)$ denotes the set of all $x \in \mathbb{A}^2$ for which $\varphi$ is defined.

From the lectures I know the following very similar theorem:

> Let $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 \in \textbf{K}(\mathbb{A}^2)$ and let $O \subseteq dom(\varphi_1) \cap dom(\varphi_2)$ be an open, non empty subset, such that $\varphi_1(x) = \varphi_2(x)$ for all $x \in U$. Then $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2$.

So if I could show that the intersection of a dense set $U$ and an open set $O$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$ is open, the exercise would be solved. However, I do not see how I could do this. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: It seems you only need to show the subset defined by $\phi_1-\phi_2$ is a closed subset.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can not follow you. What do you mean by "subset defined by $\varphi_1 - \varphi_2$" ?

Comment: You may write $\varphi_i = f_i/g_i$ where $f_i, g_i\in K[X,Y]$, and using the prescribed condition, show that the variety $V:= V(f_1 g_2 - g_1 f_2) \supset U$. Since $V$ is closed, by density of $U$ in $\mathbb{A}^2$ deduce $V = \mathbb{A}^2$. This will yield $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2$.

Comment: @kobe: I understand that $V$ is closed and $U \subseteq V$, but I do not get why this implies $V = \mathbb{A}^2$. Do you use a topological fact like: "Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. If a closed set $V \subseteq X$ contains a dense set $U$, then $V = X$." Could you please explain this?

Comment: @kobe: Ah, sorry now I get it. One characterisation of "dense" is that $V$ is dense iff $\overline{V} = X$. Thanks for the help to both of you.

Comment: @3nondatur I have put an answer keeping in mind the version of density you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\varphi_i = f_i/g_i$ for some $f_i, g_i\in K[X,Y]$, and use the given condition to show that the variety $V:= V(f_1g_2 - f_2g_1) \supset U$. Note $U$ is disjoint from the open set $\mathbb{A}^2\setminus V$, so by density of $U$ we must have $\mathbb{A}^2\setminus V = \emptyset$, or $V = \mathbb{A}^2$. Thus $\varphi_1 = \varphi_2$.